# Information about image

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

How can I get the information about image? I need file size (bytes), image size (pixels), color
mode, bits per pixel. I've already found image size (pixels) but I can't find another.

I have:

```
from skimage.io import imread

im = imread('abc.png')
print("Size: ", im.size, im.shape)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using the `Pillow library`.

This will give you all the requested information about the image except the file size.

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('whatever.png')
width, height = im.size
```

Refer to this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pillow/python_pillow_using_image_module.htm) for the attributes for the image object

In order to get the file size use this snippet below.

```
import os
print os.stat('somefile.ext').st_size
```